# SD Card Power Consumption and Optimization

Tags: mount, power-management, sd-card

I just bought a small Acer ES11 ES1-131-C514 for traveling and such. It only has 32gb of memory so I went and bought a class 10 SD card to expand the memory and sync my Dropbox on.

Is the consumption of such a SD card significant if I just leave it in permanently? If so, can I write a script or something that mounts and unmounts the SD card when I start Dropbox, or use Tlp in a way to optimize the SD card power usage?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Power_consumption

---

I know a little about power, just enough to know I actually know nothing.